# problem using jquery getjson method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am trying to use json output in jquery method.

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/items/list/", function(json) {
        var source = json;
        alert(source.os[0]);
    });
});
```

It does not work. But when I directly goto the url(/items/list/), I see the json output. 
It looks something like this..

```
{"os":["Windows","Chrome","Mac OS X"], "languages":["php", "Java"]}
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"?

Comment: Hum , it seems to work for me. It shows "Windows" as it could.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps mime type for json is not set in header before outputting:

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/items/list/", function(json) {
        var source = $.parseJSON(json);
        alert(source.os[0]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of Firefox Firebug addon that might help you .

Goto the script tab, just keep a breakpoint in the 4th line that is  var source = json; and have a look at the value of source in the right side of the firebug.

If the above doesn't help, you can try this jQuery.parseJSON( json ) which converts JSON string and returns JavaScript object.